# Use translated taxonomy labels in plugin

Tags: plugins, translation, localization, labels

I'm writing a plugin that works with taxonomy terms. It has, among other things, the capability to create new terms. I'm going to suppose that if users have custom taxonomies, they have taken care of having the singular and plural names set up and translated.

The question is: How do I format my plugin messages to use translated labels for taxonomies?

I need to output messages such as:

- "Created 1 category."
- "Matched 2 tags."
- "Updated 5 movies." (Supposing "movies" is a custom taxonomy.)

In my understanding, the (translated) singular and plural labels for a taxonomy are available as `$term_object->labels->singular_name` and `$term_object->labels->name`.

Is it correct to assume that these properties contain translated strings? Or is it necessary to wrap them with some i18n function?

The `_n()` and the `_nx()` functions provide for singular and plural forms, but it doesn't make sense using them. I've been using:

```
$message = sprintf( 
    'Created %d %s', 
    count($created), 
    count($created) == 1 ?
        $term_object->labels->singular_name
        : $term_object->labels->name 
);
```

What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a plural aware function like `_n()` or `_nx()`, because the words around the number might change in some languages depending on the amount items.
For visible numbers use `number_format_i18n()` and `%s`, not `%d`.

You cannot reuse the labels, because plural forms change depending on context in some languages.

This is how I would write your example:

```
// bare number, needed for _n()
$num  = count( $created );

// Singular or plural, we use %s, because we don't know what 
// number_format_i18n() will return.
$text = _n(
    'Created %s category',
    'Created %s categories',
    $num,
    'unique_plugin_textdomain'
);
// thousands separator etc.
$display_number = number_format_i18n( $num );
// Finally, the result:
$message        = sprintf( $text, $display_number );
```

Comment: The thing is I cannot anticipate which custom taxonomies a user might have, so I cannot provide strings for them. If they have a taxonomy called "Movies", my plugin can't know that. But you're also right about the labels not helping here, now that I think better. In Finnish, the plural label for movies would be "Elokuvat" but for the act of creating the noun goes in the accusative case: "Luotiin 5 elokuvaa". So I'm going to go with `sprintf(__n( "Created 1 term in taxonomy %s", "Created %s terms in taxonomy %s", count($created),'textdomain'), number_format_i18n( count($created)), $taxonomy );`

Comment: @HeikkiU Then let the user enter their own translation for that string.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `number_format_i18n()`

Comment: @HeikkiU How do you know the target language has an equivalent for accusative case? You don’t. :)

Comment: I understood that; that's why I said: "You're right about labels not helping here." Anyway, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [`register_taxonomy()`](http://queryposts.com/function/register_taxonomy/) expects array of translated labels and [`get_taxonomy_labels()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_taxonomy_labels/) provides translated default fallbacks.

You do not need to additionally pass labels through translation function since they assumed to be passed through it already.

Note that you do need to translate your own custom string (`Created...`).